# Create User in Azure AD with Microsoft Graph Client

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create a `User` in Azure AD with Microsoft Graph Client. I am able to create the User but I couldn't find a property for the Email or Alternative Email of the User.

Here is the code:

```
await client.Users.Request()
    .AddAsync(new User()
    {
        AccountEnabled = true,
            DisplayName = displayName,

            PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile()
            {
                ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true,
                    Password = "P@ssword123"
            },
            UserPrincipalName = $"{displayName}@{domain}",
            MailNickname = displayName,

    });
```

Comment: I think it should be `OtherMails`? :)

Comment: There is no 'OtherMails' Property :(

Comment: The library does have a `Mail` property for the user, maybe you could try that.

Comment: That is a read-only property. I even dont see any graph permission tht is need to be granted

Comment: You could also use Azure AD Graph API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#CreateUser. The User entity there does allow you to specify otherMails: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity

Comment: I have been using C# GraphClient, but making a direct httpclient call in some part of code doesn't look really nice.

Is it that C# Graph Client doesnt support this?

Comment: The client is for Microsoft Graph API, there is another client library for Azure AD Graph API: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/

Comment: @juunas But I am using Microsoft graph client

Comment: I know that :) I'm saying you could use Azure AD Graph API with the library I linked. It has the otherMails property I mentioned before for users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The User's primary email address should also be the `userPrincipalName`.

That said, the properties you're looking for are `mail` and The property is `mail` and `proxyAddresses` (this is an array of alternative SMTP addresses). These properties, however, are read-only in Microsoft Graph at the moment.

There is an open User Voice for this: [Ability to update the user's email aliases (proxyAddresses attribute)](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/17449177-ability-to-update-the-user-s-email-aliases-proxya). It could certainly use more votes (hint hint).

In order to populate these fields, you may need to use the [Azure AD Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity). The `User` object in this API includes support for writing to `mail` and `otherMails` (it also has `proxyAddresses` but that collection is also read-only).

Comment: As of May 2022, the current way to `Create User` is explained in this [article](https://damienbod.com/2022/03/11/create-azure-b2c-users-with-microsoft-graph-and-asp-net-core/). It uses the MS Graph API.